# Meteor react design - nested component: function call

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs, meteor

I'm currently facing a problem with Meteor and React, where i know some partly solutions but they don't work and imo none of them is pointing in the true direction.

The situation:

All is about an fitness app: I have a structure that represents exercises for customers, while each exercise can have a defined number of sets (a set is how often a exercise should be done). Each set has some properties (all the user can manipulate within the font-end).

Now i have the following component structure with some map-functions (state properties are in {}):

```
Training {customers,exercises,datetime,otherinfos}
    - Overview {customers,exercises}
         exercises.map():
         - Exercise {exercise,customers}
              customers.map():
              - Customer {exercise,customer}
                    exercise.sets.map()
                    Set {exercise, customer, set, valuesofset}
```

From a UI-perspective (react) this all works without problems.

Now the idea is to have a button "Save" within the Training component. When the button is pressed, I want to save the state of all Set-Components in a "sets" collection (if it has other values than the default placeholder ones) and at the same time save the Training-Component in a "trainings" collection. But the training should also include information about what Sets are integrated (so at least the Set._id should be in the Training-Component state at time of Saving.

Here now my ideas so far:

1. Create refs from Training all the way down to all Sets and then, when pressing "Save" iterate over all refs and call a "Mongo.insert" from all Sets. Here i have the problem that i cannot return the inserted _id. Of course i could call a different function in each Component from Set all the way back to Training, but imo this is an overflow.
2. Try to manage the state of all sets within the Training state by calling a nested function. As i have onChangeHandler on the Inputs, this would always call a method in Training and check which one of the Sets was changed and then changes it. I have tried it this way, but it led to a very bad performance.
3. Create a temp-ID for Training, forward it to to the Sets (using the componentWillReceiveProps method) and when in Set, insert the Set in the database with the temp-ID. Then receive all Sets with temp-ID and use it to add the Training in the database. --> imo very complicated and I don't really want to do a database call if it is not necessary.

So currently i don't know how to solve this problem. The reason i try to separate "sets" and "trainings" is given through the fact, that later on i would like to give information about the last Set right next to the new empty Set whenever one is on the database. Any tips are welcome!

---

EDIT:

As suggested, there is also the possibility to solve the problem with Session. So therefor i have added the following code to Set:

```
componentDidMount() {
    Tracker.autorun(() => {
        Session.set(`set_${this.state.id}`, {
            ...this.state
        });
    });
}
```

My idea was then to iterate over all Session-Keys from Training which start with "set_" - unfortunately there is no function to that holds all Keys.

Second idea was to to use an array as value for a Session-pair. However, it's quite a procedure to handle the update of the reactive Set component (copy array from session, check whether an element is available or not, create a new one or update the existing one).

---

EDIT2:

I think i got a solution with Session:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Session.keys)
```

did the trick to get all SessionKeys! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sounds like you need something like `redux` to manage non-local state.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately i though i could leave out redux here when using Meteor, especially as Redux it is mostly used for UI state, but UI state works fine without it in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use Redux or pass parent bound callbacks in the child component, you can try Session to store data at app level which can be accessed(set/get) in any component

https://docs.meteor.com/api/session.html

In your case, you may set values of "Set" in Session and access it in Training. You may also need https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#using-withTracker. Using withTracker will help in doing reactive update of the database on change of any Session variable.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this idea! I tried it and thought it would be the solution, unfortunately it is quite hard to get the IDs (check the updated main post)

Comment: Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Session.keys) did the trick! Thanks for the Session hint!

Comment: I'm just wondering which one could be considered as the best practice?